# spark load a s3a file as a df, which command to run?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-submit

I have a json file that is valid:

I can successfully import it on a local spark machine

```
DF = sqlContext.read.json("/home/me/myfile.json")
```

I have a shell script to submit the job

```
/home/me/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--master local[*] Code.py
```

So far so good, for example DF.show(1) works fine.

Now I am trying to load from a s3a link (which contains exactely the same data as myfile.json).

I have tried

```
DF = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://some-bucket/myfile.json")
```

I still run my shell script that contains the same command, i.e.

```
/home/me/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--master local[*] Code.py
```

But this time it does not work, I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

Is my shell script wrong?

PS: I just got the s3a link from someone else. So it's not on my AWS account. I assume that I still can import the data from that link even if I do not know any accesskey or secretkey...

Comment: It's a `ClassNotFoundException``. Have you checked your dependencies?

Comment: no, how do I do that?

Comment: I fixed the dependencies by adding both haddop-aws-2.7.3.jar and aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar inside /spar/jars file. Nevertheless I get the following error now : Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could resolve the issue. By adding the right .jar file (see my comment below) and setting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY inside the spark-env.sh which is located in the conf folder of my spark folder.

Thanks